# updating gem without breaking other's code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

In rails, I need use google_drive gem to access spreadsheet. The google_drive depends on the updated google-api-client. If I update google-api-client, the update may broke other's code. 
How could I get this around?

Here's error msg:

```
 Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "google-api-client": (Bundler::VersionConflict)
  In snapshot (Gemfile.lock):
    google-api-client (= 0.6.4)

  In Gemfile:
    google_drive (>= 0) ruby depends on
      google-api-client (>= 0.7.0) ruby

    google-api-client (>= 0) ruby
```

Comment: You can't. That's going to happen. If their code just happens to require the old version of `google-api-client` then you're going to have to branch your project. Or hotswap the gems in your Gemfile which just sounds...awful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run this locally, then run your spec suite:

```
bundle update google-api-client
```

If there's a spec suite in place, and it is thorough, it should find any issues you may cause by updating the gem.